# Getting two different returned columns from one table but different filters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I need certain data from one table and then I need to join on another. However the joined table has only 1 column I need but I need it to return it in 2 different columns based on what type of information is in it.

For example:

Table 1

```
Key  ID  
123  1
789  2
```

Table 2

```
Key  Type  Name
123  R     Red
123  B     Blue
789  R     Black
789  D     DULL
```

Table 3 (the results I am trying to return)

```
Key  Type R  Type B
123  Red     Blue
789  Black
```

There can be more than just Type R and Type B so I need to make sure I am only returning that information but specifically put that information in the Table 3 respected columns.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: Downvote for not specifying whether you're using MySQL or SQL-Server.

Comment: Sorry,  SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2r.name as r_name, t2b.name as b_name
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2r
     on t2r.key = t1.key and t2r.type = 'R' left join
     table2 t2b
     on t2b.key = t1.key and t2b.type = 'B';
```

This is standard SQL and the same in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select [Key]
              ,Item=concat('Type ',[Type])
              ,Value=[Name] 
         From  YourTable
         Where [Type] in ('R','B')
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ([Type R],[Type B]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
Key Type R  Type B
123 Red     Blue
789 Black   NULL
```